# Не переводится одно слово в проекте с PoEdit

Tags: ubuntu

Я обнаружил, что в проекте не переводится одно слово Images (остальные переводятся). Открыл файл *.po и не обнаружил там соответствующей записи. Попробовал дописать вручную в Шторме:

```
msgid "Images"
msgstr "Изображения"
```

Однако безрезультатно. После скачал Poedit и с его помощью отредактировал этот файл — ничего не изменилось. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вполне возможно, что это слово может использоваться как в единственном, так и во множественном числе. Посмотрите, есть ли в вашем PO файле строки, вроде `msgid_plural "Images"`

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev посмотрел - нет такой строки.

Comment: Отлично, а в коде приложения точно используется строка `Images` в качестве ключа?

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev да, именно так: `<th><?php __("Images"); ?></th>`

Comment: Значит это либо кэширование .po файлов, либо магия :)

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev я так понимаю, что если кэширование, то не проблема сбросить кэш. А если магия - как тогда дальше действовать?

Comment: По-хорошему, я не вижу причин, почему бы оно не работало.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64537/discussion-between--and-dmitriy-simushev).

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev очистка кэша проблему не решила, к сожалению.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64545/discussion-between--and-dmitriy-simushev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблемы больше нет - сегодня включил комп, всё переведено. Вывод - загвоздка была в кэше скрипта. Всем спасибо за помощь!